# How to encrypt in javascript and decrypt that in php with out using any external file

Tags: javascript, php

**This is the code to take the input and then encrypt the content by java script**
The entire code is also available in github.you guys can search for it encrypt_js_decrypt_php.
The problem was running since long.I have come up with the solution.Just import it into localhost.

```
<input type="text" id="code" name="code"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return encryptCode();"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function rc4(key, str)
{
    var s = [], j = 0, x, res = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
    {
        s[i] = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
    {
        j = (j + s[i] + key.charCodeAt(i % key.length)) % 256;
        x = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = x;
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < str.length; y++) 
    {
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + s[i]) % 256;
        x = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = x;
        res += String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(y) ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256]);
    }
    return res;
}

function encryptCode()
{
  var value = document.getElementById("code").value;
  var key = "secretKeyToProvide";  /*--Provide Your secret key here--*/
  var codeValue = rc4(key, value);
  var arr = {code:codeValue, Age:25};
  $.ajax({
                url: "response.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(arr),
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });   
}
</script>
</html>
```

Now,lets decrypt the code in php

```
<?php

function mb_chr($char) 
{
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#'.intval($char).';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}

function mb_ord($char)
{
    $result = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
    if (is_array($result) === true) 
    {
        return $result[1];
    }
        return ord($char);
}

function rc4($key, $str) 
{   
    if (extension_loaded('mbstring') === true) 
    {
        mb_language('Neutral');
        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
        mb_detect_order(array('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15', 'ISO-8859-1', 'ASCII'));
    }
    $s = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
    {
        $s[$i] = $i;
    }
    $j = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
    {
        $j = ($j + $s[$i] + mb_ord(mb_substr($key, $i % mb_strlen($key), 1))) % 256;
        $x = $s[$i];
        $s[$i] = $s[$j];
        $s[$j] = $x;
    }
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $res = '';
    for ($y = 0; $y < mb_strlen($str); $y++)
    {
        $i = ($i + 1) % 256;
        $j = ($j + $s[$i]) % 256;
        $x = $s[$i];
        $s[$i] = $s[$j];
        $s[$j] = $x;
        $res .= mb_chr(mb_ord(mb_substr($str, $y, 1)) ^ $s[($s[$i] + $s[$j]) % 256]);
    }
    return $res;
}

$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($request_body);
$secretCode =$json->code ;
$age =$json->Age  ;
$key = "secretKeyToProvide";  /*--Provide Your secret key here what you have given in javascript--*/
$decryptedSecretCode  = rc4($key, $secretCode) ;
echo $decryptedSecretCode;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Did you have a question, or are you trying to teach us something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an answer to a question that was not asked

Comment: I am giving an answer to the question